# Small inductor coil in VCC, why did it help?

Tags: noise, communication

I have two devices - I know nothing about their internal circuits - and they  communicate with each other.

The communication between them is made by four wires, VCC, GND and two communication wires.

One of the devices supplies power to the other.  For communication to occur it is necessary to place a coiled wire in the VCC between the two.

I do 3 turns on the VCC wire and a diameter of about 5mm as shown in the picture.

After that the communication between them occurs without problems.

Could anyone explain why it worked when I do the coil with the VCC wire? Is it a noise matter?

[image]

Comment: There are many reasons that could be. Without a schematic it would be pretty hard to chose the right one. BTW, I have a strong doubt that the fact that this wire is shaped as a coil has any significance.

Comment: Without further information, the best answer I can give is "because you changed the circuit" Please document

Comment: Daniel, this kind of fix-up seems highly unusual. The first thing that I imagine is that you've done other things not documented in your question in order to apply the coil, or when not applying it, that we don't know about which is the real issue and the coil is a red herring. But if the coil really is important then this suggests some high frequency problem (call it noise if you like) that is being blocked by this simple addition. You might try sliding a bead over a direct wire (no coil) and see if that also works, in this case. Experiment. Let us know what you uncover.

Comment: If the coil *is* what fixed it, my guess is there's probably a bad connection and the presence of the coil applies a force on that connection to hold it in place.

Comment: I saw this asked somewhere before and it was answerd...It was either on here or another forum I frequent.

Comment: What are the two devices? Please an _in focus_ photo of the complete setup.

Comment: The power supply could be very noisy, and the coil could be forming part of a low-pass which blocks enough of the noise to stop it from interfering with the communications.

Comment: @jonk, I don't have a bead here with me, but I suspect, based in the comments here, that the problem could be a poor connection, so, 
 I desoldered the connections and solder it again, after doing this the communication wokked fine. But, when I try to read it using a oscilloscope the communication fails. It is very strange.